# button fixed when scrolling but not under elements

Tags: css, html

I am building an HTML5 website and I have put a button on the right top of the page which will be fixed if I scroll down.

This is working but with some paragraphs the button is going underneath.

It is a button to buy tickets and it has to be above all the items all the time.
Some `<p>` or `<div>` are absolute and I think that's the problem.

Comment: Could you paste your code and create an reproducible example in codepen, jsfiddle...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a z-index to it

```
.your-button{
    z-index:9999;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you explain me what is this doing? :-)

Comment: z-index basiclt tells your element where to be on the z axis. The lower the number the closer it will be to the ground. The higher the number the higher it will be basicly. Knowing this you can place multiple items on top of each other.

Comment: Hi again,
the button is perfect now but i set a min-width 1441px for bigger screen and the button is actually going out on the left when i resize the screen for bigger screen!!! Why? doesn't supposed to be fixed there?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the problem is possibly with the `absolute` positioning. This elements are in a higher plane than the static content. Possible fixes are:

1. Removing the `absolute` from those `div`.
2. Make your button `absolute` and if that doesn't help, change the
   `z-index` which referes to the position in the z-axis(deepth).